# Moodle local plugin development creating user access

Tags: plugins, moodle, moodle-api

I am creating a new local plugin on moodle that nedd to be accessed by users that are not admin, i tried to create a new item on the left navigation bar but didn't get and i was told to not do it, i was able to create a link in the site administration but the user intended to use the plugin has no access to the site administration, so i need to create a way to access the plugin without using the plugin link(preferably by the interface):

my settings.php file

```
<?php
$ADMIN->add('localplugins', new admin_externalpage('local_myplugin', 'myplugin', $CFG->wwwroot.'/local/myplugin/manage.php'));
```

Comment: You can add the plugin settings link on the PROFILE page of the user who has the capability to access your plugin configs.

Comment: I think what you need is extending the global navigation. See https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Navigation_API#Local_Plugins

Comment: thanks a lot! i will take a look.